# "The headers or library files could not be found for zlib, a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source"

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library, pyautogui

I am trying to run a Python program with pyautogui but there's a problem because it is telling me that Pillow is not installed. I tried to install it or upgrade it with commands such as

```
pip install Pillow --upgrade
```

but nothing worked.

On the documentation they say that Pillow doesn't coexist with PIL so we need to uninstall it but I can't because it says that it is not installed.

The error is:

```
The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
      a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
```

and also

```
Collecting Pillow
  Using cached Pillow-9.2.0.tar.gz (50.0 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: Pillow
  Building wheel for Pillow (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
```

Comment: The error is not exactly about that Pillow is missing, but about the dependencies of `zlib` (*The headers or library files could not be found for zlib*), which seems to be one of Pillow's dependencies. You need to be able to install zlib first, to install Pillow.

Answer (score 8):

You need [`zlib-dev`](https://pkgs.org/download/zlib-devel). This installs the headers that you need to compile parts of Pillow.

You will likely come across the same message for `jpeg`; for this, you need the [`libjpeg-turbo-dev`](https://pkgs.org/search/?q=libjpeg-turbo-dev) package.

Comment: Good point, but I am not sure which distribution and version you are referring to. For instance, Debian wheezy seems to have different packages.

Comment: @Wtower Indeed. These are the package names for much of the debian family. Usually, RPM distros use `-devel` instead of `-dev`. Click the links in my answer; pkgs.org shows you the package name across over 50 different distros, which is why I only put in the names for Debian.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that @vpseg. I hadn’t properly noticed the links.

Comment: zlib1g-dev  and libjpeg-dev on Debian Buster worked - thanks

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue on my mac. For me, after running the following commands, it worked:

```bash
brew install zlib
brew install jpeg
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include"
```

Comment: My homebrew used a different folder. I needed export `LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib"` and export `CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include"`. The relevant folder can be found using `brew --prefix zlib`

Comment: This gets things working for me, but with this caveat from brew: `zlib is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /opt/homebrew, because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.`. If macOS already provides the same software, why can't the compiler use it by default?

Answer (score -3):

if you are linux user you can do this

```
pip install pillow
```

or

```
sudo apt install python3-pil
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, sadly I am on windows and the pip install pillow doesn't work and give me this error... could it be because of my python version ?

Comment: no its not about your python version, what about pip ? did you installed it, and work fine?

Comment: whiche version of python your are using ? 2 or 3

Comment: I am using python Python 3.9.13 and the pip version is the most recent

Comment: try this pip install wheel

Comment: it is already installed...