# Installing Pillow on Windows with 32-bit Python

Tags: pip, python-imaging-library, 32-bit

I'm getting this error while running pip install pillow.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\python39-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
      main()
    File "c:\python39-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "c:\python39-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
      return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
    File "C:\Users\AfrouzA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ldehb4hc\pillow_fab211561b6345c2962286f7fb8be3f4\_custom_build\backend.py", line 53, in build_wheel
      return super().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings, metadata_directory)
    File "C:\Users\AfrouzA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mn8zg9s3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 434, in build_wheel
      return self._build_with_temp_dir(
    File "C:\Users\AfrouzA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mn8zg9s3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 419, in _build_with_temp_dir
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\AfrouzA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ldehb4hc\pillow_fab211561b6345c2962286f7fb8be3f4\_custom_build\backend.py", line 47, in run_setup
      return super().run_setup(setup_script)
    File "C:\Users\AfrouzA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-mn8zg9s3\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 1005, in <module>
  __main__.RequiredDependencyException:

  The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
  a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.

  Please see the install instructions at:
     https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html

  [end of output]
```

> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
> ERROR: Failed building wheel for pillow
> Failed to build pillow
> ERROR: Could not build wheels for pillow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
> WARNING: There was an error checking the latest version of pip.

I upgraded pip. Now I'm running pip 23.3 from C:\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9).

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["The headers or library files could not be found for zlib, a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73598578/the-headers-or-library-files-could-not-be-found-for-zlib-a-required-dependency)

Comment: Says you're missing some components from zlib.  Do you have the dependencies installed?

Comment: Trying to install zlib, however I cannot find any clear documentation for that. 
How to install dependencies? where to install? (same location as scripts and pips or need to install in the lib folder?)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a 32-bit version of Python installed. From Pillow 10, precompiled 32-bit wheels are no longer provided:

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes/10.0.0.html#bit-wheels

pip is therefore trying to build from source, and you don't have the necessary dependencies.

Options:

- Install a 64-bit version of Python: https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/
- Install `pillow<10`
- Install dependencies to build from source: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#building-from-source

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you have a 32-bit version of Python?

Comment: Thanks, you're right. after installing 64 bit version of python I could run all the libraries. Python 32 is not working with pillow.